# how do I match this url

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

Hey, how do I match the url that starts with digits which are followed by "?fmt=json", like 1234?fmt=json return true but my another wep handler which handles the urls that are all digits like 1234 return false? I have tried \d+(?!\?fmt=json) which is supposed match the url where the digits are not followed by "?fmt=json", but it doesnt work. any helps? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression only matches when the fmt=json suffix is there and will "return false" if only numbers:

```
\d+\?fmt=json
```

Like

```
http://something/1234?fmt=json   == true, (match=1234?fmt=json)
http://something/1234            == false
```

[See here in a regex tester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=1234%5C?fmt=json&input=http://something/1234?fmt=json%0Ahttp://something/1234)

Comment: +1 And very cool link to RegexPal complete with regex and test data in query string. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

You can't match the query string in App Engine's webapp, or most other Python webapp frameworks. It's a rather odd thing to want to do, too - your handler should fetch the value of the argument, and modify its output based on that.